# Running many, many Android emulators on a host and hitting some limit?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm experimenting with running a huge number of Android emulator instances on a single Linux host. I'm doing the following:

1. Starting up 10 emulator instances
2. Sending all the emulators a SIGSTOP signal to stop them
3. Goto 1

I made it to 58 emulators running, then I started seeing the following when trying to start more instances:

```
ko:Invalid (null) partition size 0x0
```

Continuing to try eventually yields these messages:

```
it seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine. Aborting
```

It seems like this is some limit within the emulator itself (since all the other emulator instances are stopped, they should be able to be swapped out, which was indeed happening properly until I hit 58 instances).

What limit am I hitting? A limit on the number of network ports available to the instances? Something else?

Comment: Continuing my attempts, I was able to get a few more instances to launch. It appears to max out at 64 instances (a suspiciously nice number) so I have an even stronger feeling that this is some internal limit within the emulator, or how adb expects to work

Comment: maybe your RAM? or virtualization tech?

Comment: 16 GB of RAM with 32 GB of swap. I can increase that and see if it makes any difference.